# How do you install "extra" versions of backport packages in debian?

Tags: linux, debian, patch-management

I want to install the extra nginx version [nginx-full package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/nginx-full) from debian backports - but when I try to run the install command it says that the package is not found.

```
$ apt-get -t squeeze-backports install nginx-full
```

I have followed the [backports instructions](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/). I want the Limit Requests / Limit Zone modules not available in the standard `apt-get install nginx` install.

Comment: There don't appear to be any nginx package backports for squeeze, yet: http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze-backports&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there are no nginx packages on backports yet ([search result here](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze-backports&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=nginx))

Update 2012-11-29, courtesy of @white_gecko:

It appears that the packages are now available.

Comment: Hmmm, that would explain it. I just assumed they existed because the install page lists squeeze as the current repo and sid is where the packages are.

Comment: Looks like dotdeb has my back: http://www.dotdeb.org/2011/03/12/nginx-now-on-dotdeb/